# Setting the value of protection days for jobs 'ContentStoreCleanerTrigger' and 'NodeServiceCleanupTrigger' in Alfresco 5.1?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I have `Alfresco 5.1` server with some unused content in repository and old workflow instances.
I'm going to remove this content with UI Alfresco Share/scripts.

The clean repo will used as template of database Alfresco (it's catalog `data` + `db`).

I know that the standrd job `ContentStoreCleanerTrigger` does not move content from the `contentstore` to the `contentstore.deleted` directory until 14 days after it was removed from the trash.  This provides safety net in case content was inadvertently deleted.
Additionally, the jobs `NodeServiceCleanupTrigger` runs every day and purges information related to deleted nodes from the database (I don't know are there some protections days too).

I want to change this behavior before I'll purge the trashcan, but could't find documentation.
Otherwise I will have to wait a long time before deleted files will moved to `contentstore.deleted`.

How can I set the protection days value for jobs `ContentStoreCleanerTrigger`, `NodeServiceCleanupTrigger`?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google points to the official docs: [Cleaning up orphaned content (purge)](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/clean-content.html) but I would recommend Toni's Blog: [Understanding Alfresco Content Deletion](https://blyx.com/2014/08/18/understanding-alfresco-content-deletion/)

In short: set parameters in alfresco-global.properties

```
# keep content 14 days before cleaning up 
system.content.orphanProtectDays=14
# don't move the content to contentstore.deleted - just delete it!
system.content.eagerOrphanCleanup=true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! It was helpfull.